# MySQL Query Limit Between Two Value

Tags: php, mysql

I am new in PHP and trying to get result from table between two value. I want get first row 0 to 5 numbers and so I have written query like below

```
$sql = "SELECT number, status, user_id 
        from number_list 
        WHERE disable=0 
        LIMIT 0,5";
```

But its not giving me first 5 rows. Its providing some other values. Let me know what is issue and how can I get row between two numbers ?

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to add `order by` clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use limit 5 for first 5 rows

```
 $sql = "SELECT number, status, user_id from number_list WHERE disable=0 LIMIT 5 ";
```

anyway when  the use limit should be better use  order by  too .. eg

```
 $sql = "SELECT number, status, user_id from number_list WHERE disable=0 
   order by number LIMIT 5 ";
```

Comment: Add order by to Your Query:
SELECT number, status, user_id from number_list WHERE disable=0 order by number LIMIT 5

Comment: @scaisEdge Thanks! its working like charm ! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @scaisEdge I will sure do it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change `LIMIT 0,5";`  to `LIMIT 5";` - limit takes only integers.